# Check if files share same ending in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how would i check if all files in specific directory `dir/` share the same file ending `.txt`.

This is how I find the files:

```py
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(dir):
    print(files)
```

Comment: Hint: use the `all` function, the `endswith` method, and a generator expression.

Comment: You can use a not to invert the check in [one of these answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Addition to chepner's hints, you might want to use `str.lower` to cover an extension like `.tXt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_end_with_txt = True
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
                if not file.lower().endswith('.txt'):
                        all_end_with_txt = False
```